# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate fails, returns null

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've got a Mongoose schema for an object called Plot which works fine when it comes to saving. However, when I try to update those plots with the code below, it fails, returning null:

```
exports.updatePlot = async (req, res) => {
    let updates = { ...req.body.props };
    const id = updates._id;
    if (updates.plannedYield) {
        const plannedYield = Number(updates.plannedYield);
        const metrics = {
            yield: { day120CustomerEstimation: plannedYield }
        };
        updates.metrics = metrics;
        delete updates.plannedYield;
    }
    console.log(updates);
    try {
        console.log('updating plot');
        const updatedPlot = await Plot.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updates, {
            new: true
        });
        if (!updatedPlot) {
            console.log("couldn't update plot");
        }
        console.log(('updated  plot saved:', updatedPlot));
        res.json({
            updatedPlot
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
        return res.status(422).send({
            error: { message: 'e', resend: true }
        });
    }
};
```

This results in the following console output:

```
{ id: '5aa65801c97d496ef457b802',
  metrics: { yield: { day120CustomerEstimation: 1 } } }
updating plot
couldn't update plot
null
```

Can anyone suggest a fix? I've tried casting id to ObjectId, which didn't do the trick.

Comment: Is `_id` or `id` in your `req.body.props` ? The `console.log` suggests the later but `const id = updates._id;`  assumes the former. Also, you probably want to remove the id from `updates` object.

Comment: That was it. Thank you, good call. If you add as an answer, I'll accept.